# Typescript + Angular 4: How to clear viewContainerRef by listening to changes in a service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component, where I have:

```
@ViewChild('section1', {read: ViewContainerRef}) cc1;
@ViewChild('section2', {read: ViewContainerRef}) cc2;
```

etc... Now sometimes I want to remove the data in the containers, right now I have a button on that component that calls a function with `this.cc1.clear(), ...`.

But what I would rather do is remove that button, and when a variable changes in a service, I want to do the same function,

I have another component which is a group of buttons, which put out:

```
this.myService.variable.next('value1');
this.myService.variable.next('value2');
```

In my service I have:

```
public variable = new BehaviorSubject('');
```

Now in my first component, I put in my constructor:

```
myService.variable.subscribe((val) => {
      console.log('my value is: ' + val);
     });
```

Now, in my console it logs fine, but if I add `this.cc1.clear()` under the `console.log` line, On my app the component doesnt load, and i get an error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'clear' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear' of
>   undefined
>       at SafeSubscriber._next

I'm still all fairly new to Angular, so what is it that I'm doing wrong and how to accomplish this?

Comment: _Now in my first component, I put in my constructor:_ - show the full code of a component

Answer (score 0):

A look through some documentation and esspeicially https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/angular2-difference-between-a-behavior-subject-and-an-observable/, shows to get the effect, use regular subjects rather than behaivor-subjects.

```
public subject = new Subject();
```